# Is it possible not to load theme on a specific page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I have a question about WordPress, I need the current theme installed on my WordPress not to be loaded on a certain page, is it possible?

What I want to do is create a bootstrap dashboard, and I don't want to load the default theme. The idea is to develop a dashboard via plugin and generate all the HTML, header, content, footer.

I thought about using "WP_USE_THEME" and using external files, but I need to use WordPress functions like: `add_action`, `add_shortcode` and etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your dashboard will be doing. In particular, will it be displaying content from wp_posts?

Comment: Yes of course. The panel that I will develop will have a series of resources, from seeing the posts to the information that I will store, I have some plugins that save the evaluations of the posts in the database. So it is to show different information. I will develop in bootstrap, I already have something developed already, but the theme I use conflicts with some bootstrap features, so I needed to disable it when accessing my panel, which is currently in a plugin using shortcode!

I hope you understand. Thank you.

Comment: In your external file you can load the WordPress environment by including the file "wp-load.php". This only loads the WordPress core. Depending on your requirements you may need to load additional files.

Comment: This gives you access to many (but not all) WordPress functions but no HTML will have been emitted including HTTP headers. Also, the current user would be set.

Comment: So, I thought of this solution. It would work in parts, using "wp-load.php" I would not be able to use the hooks. So I am creating the dashboard as a plugin.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205088/how-to-remove-all-styles-for-certain-page-template

The above solution helped me in parts, much of the theme is not loaded, I no longer have code conflict with bootstrap. But the idea is not to issue any html or wordpress http headers.

I look forward to other possible solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: using "wp-load.php" I would not be able to use the hooks. - Why do you think this is true? I don't think this is correct - I will need to reread the source code but wp-load.php is used to initialize AJAX handling where hooks work.

Comment: I just read the source code. Hooks are implemented by class-wp-hook.php which is loaded by plugin.php which is loaded by load.php which is loaded by wp-settings.php which is loaded by wp-config.php which is loaded by wp-load.php. So hooks will be available after  wp-load.php is done.

Comment: Specific hooks may not be available if it is found in code not in the WordPress core but then you just have to include that non-core code also and that hook will be available.

Comment: Does your code use the WordPress loop? If so you can use the action 'template_redirect'

Comment: So I need to use some specific hooks. I believe I found a good solution, which is to replace the standard template. It is the "template_include" filter. Basically in my plugin it checks the current page id and if it is the page I want to replace the template with the one I created, which contains my head, body and footer.

I read this article: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208181/how-to-add-custom-template-in-plugin

I'll wait a while to see if new ideas come up, if not, it's resolved!
Thanks @Magenta Cuda!

Answer (score 0):

You can use function switch_theme() in hook plugins_loaded to switch the theme run time. You can use below code for reference.

Don't forget to add your condition. Also, note that switching theme runtime may cause peformance issue.

````
    // switch_theme('astra');
    // switch_theme('automotive-centre');
    // switch_theme('blocksy');
    // switch_theme('customify');
    // switch_theme('generatepress');
    // switch_theme('hello-elementor');
    // switch_theme('inbox');
    // switch_theme('magcess');
    // switch_theme('myself');
    // switch_theme('newsphere');
    // switch_theme('oceanwp');
    // switch_theme('page-builder-framework');
    // switch_theme('shopical');
    // switch_theme('storement');
    // switch_theme('twentyfifteen');
    // switch_theme('twentynineteen');
    // switch_theme('twentyseventeen');
    // switch_theme('twentysixteen');
    // switch_theme('vw-ecommerce-store');
    // 
    if( isset( $_GET['theme'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['theme'] ) ) {
        $theme_slug = sanitize_title( $_GET['theme'] );
        $theme_slugs = array_keys(wp_get_themes( ));
        if( in_array($theme_slug, $theme_slugs) ) {
            switch_theme( $theme_slug );
        } else {
            wp_die( sprintf( __( 'Theme not found!<br/><b>%s</b> slug! Please try again with right theme slug.', 'woocommerce' ), $theme_slug ) );
        }
    }
});```
````